# HTML button to submit a form elsewhere on the page

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button

I want to have a form on the main section of my webpage with buttons along the bottom of this section to submit it.

I also want to have a side bar with links to other pages, but make it so that whenever a link is clicked it acts as a button to submit the form too. (ie in the HTML, the code for these links will be outside of the form tags, but I would like them to still act as buttons for the form)

Is this possible?

Comment: The solution in most answers is to use JS to submit the form. Beware that the submit handler is not called if you call `form.submit()`. Therefore, if you do have an `onsubmit` handler to validate the form, you must call the validation routine yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to ensure your form is submitted *and* validated by whatever function you've attached is not to call the form's `submit()` method, but to call its submit button's `click()` method instead.

Consider the following form:

```
<form id="bar" method="post" action="/echo/html/">
    <input type="text" id="foo" name="foo">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Right now, clicking submit doesn't do anything special. But what if you wanted to ensure the text input had a value before sending anything off to the server? You might accomplish that as follows:

```
function validateBarForm() {
    var txt = this.querySelector("input[type=text]");
    if (txt.value == "") {
        txt.style.outline = "solid red 2px";
        return false;
    }
}

document.getElementById("bar").onsubmit = validateBarForm;
```

Now if you click submit the form won't be submitted with a blank text input. But what if you submit the form programmatically? Let's add a link first...

```
<a href="#" id="submit-bar">submit form</a>
```

Note that this link is *outside* of the form tag. We can trivially attach a submission function:

```
function submitBarForm() {
    document.getElementById("bar").submit();
}

document.getElementById("submit-bar").onclick = submitBarForm;
```

We click "submit form" and... Whoops! The validation function is not performed! There are a few ways to skirt this issue, but my favourite is to simply have JavaScript simulate a click to the submit button. I find this holds up to changes a lot better than hardcoding a call to the validation function.

```
function submitBarForm() {
    document.querySelector("#bar input[type=submit]").click();
}
```

Now when you click the link, the form is validated, and if everything checks out it's submitted too. But don't take my word for it--head on over to jsfiddle.net and see for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following `onclick` handler in your link, replacing `formId` with the ID for the form you want to submit...

```
onclick="document.getElementById('formId').submit();return false;"
```

**Update**

As @Juan (and others, especially @JoeTaylor) have mentioned, the above will not fire any client-side validation code associated with the form.  The easiest way that I'm aware of to make it do so is to fire the `click` event of a submit button within the form.  For instance, this could be used on your link...

```
onclick="document.getElementById('formSubmitButton').click();return false;"
```

Although you don't mention anything to do with server-side processing, I will take the assumption that is the point of your form.  One additional thing I would say on the back of this is that you should **ALWAYS** replicate the validation back on the server.  JavaScript is very easy to bypass, and so you should make sure the values reaching your server are correct, and **never** assume the JavaScript has done it's job.

Comment: Will this fire the submit event? That is, if I have an onsubmit that needs to do some validation, won't calling submit from JS bypass that handler?

Comment: @Juan, that is a very good point, and no I don't believe it will. As has already been mentioned in other answers, the easiest way would be to "click" a submit button within the form - I will update my answer to give an example

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this very easy without JavaScript in HTML5:

```
<input type="submit" form="id_of_the_form" value="Submit">

<form id="id_of_the_form" action method></form>
```

And you can style those buttons as you like. As in the example, the button can be placed at any point within the dom - no need to put it into the form.

Comment: Compatibility: it works almost everywhere except Internet Explorer (source: http://www.impressivewebs.com/html5-form-attribute/ )

Answer (score 0):

By adding an onclick javascript function to your form.

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```

Where "myform" is the id of your form. Here's a nice walkthrough: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

For example, the button might be:

```
<button onclick="document.forms['myform'].submit();">Hi</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes the button's click event add `document.getElementById('formId').submit();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<form name="myform" action="action.php">

    // Your form

</form>

<a href="javascript: document.myform.submit();">Submit form</a>
```

Or you can use jQuery:

```
<form name="myform" action="action.php">

    // Your form

</form>

<a href="#" onclick="$("#myform").submit();">Your text</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this myself with hidden submit buttons in the actual form, and outside of the form - anywhere else on the page - labels that reference the submit button and fire it.

In the form:

```
<input type='submit' id='hiddenSubmit'>
```

And anywhere else:

```
<label for='hiddenSubmit'>click me!</label>
```

Seems to do the job.